# how to execute 3D-fft in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, fft

I have to transform an input column of 1024 complex value with 3D-fft in matlab. Dimensions are: Nx = 32 Ny = 16 Nz = 2.

What can I do?

Comment: The multi-dimensional FFT is a [separable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906956/is-2d-fft-separable) operation. That means you can simply apply FFT along each dimension (so three uni-dimensional FFT's)

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

## Option #1 - Apply FFT in each dimension separately

You can manually apply the FFT in each dimension separately.  Luis Mendo pointed out that the FFT is a separate operation.  You can use the [`fft`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) function to help you do that.  Given that your signal is stored in `A`, do something like this:

```
B = fft(fft(fft(A, [], 1), [], 2), [], 3);
```

Because the operation is separable, it doesn't matter which order you apply the `fft` to.  Here, I did it over the columns, then rows, then slices.

## Option #2 - Use `fftn`

Alternatively, you can use [`fftn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftn.html) which does the above for you under the hood.  This is the N-Dimensional FFT and the documentation says that the equivalent code that `fftn` performs under the hood is:

```
Y = X;
for p = 1:length(size(X))
    Y = fft(Y,[],p);
end
```

Take note that the above code is essentially doing what Option #1 is doing, but we did this without any loops and nested called `fft` three times.

Now, the above code assumes that your signal is stored in `X`.... so:

```
Y = fftn(X);
```

.... is what you'd do.